# ASP.NET - Enabling button by reading data in Grid View inside Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have two Buttons and GridView which are:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn-search" runat="server" OnClick=btn_search_Click />
<asp:Button ID="btn-export" runat="server" OnClick=btn_export_Click />
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" />
```

`btn-search` is a control to bind data to the `gridview1` from an `SqlDataSource`. `btn-export` is disabled at `Page_Load` and will be enabled when `gridview1` has at least one row (`btn-export` will stay disabled if there is no data/row in `gridview1`).

At first I wrote this in code behind:

```
    protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* Binding data to GridView */
        if (this.gridview1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.btn_export.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

and it worked.

But, then I have to wrap the `gridview1` in an `UpdatePanel` so it wont refresh the whole page when data binding in GridView, using `btn-search` as `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="btn-search" runat="server" OnClick=btn_search_Click />
<asp:Button ID="btn-export" runat="server" OnClick=btn_export_Click />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_search" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When the data was bound to `gridview1`, the `btn-search` still disabled.
I try to write `this.btn_export.Enabled = true` in GridView and UpdatePanel event such as `OnDataBound`, `OnDataBinding`, `OnRowDataBound` but it still not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grayfield, it doesnt work because when you click the search button only the update panel content is updated.
Try adding the buttons inside the ContentTemplate of the update panel and it should work.